# save data to long in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I made a button for save the results input data. but in process of saving too long. can this process take quickly? this is line I write:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i as Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 366 
        If range("C" & i + 67) <> "" Then 
            range("E" & i + 67) = "EB": End If
        If Format(range("A" & i + 67), "dddd") = "Sunday" Then
            range("E" & i + 67) = "AP"
        If range("D" & i + 67) = "" Then
            range("D" & i + 67) = "Aspalt"
        End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe turn off automatic calculations as well. There is doubtless a more efficient way of doing things, but with only 366 passes through the loop, there is no reason for code like this to take more than a fraction of a second. This code is interacting with something else. Also -- what does this code have to do with *saving* data? There is writing to the worksheet, but no saving as saving is usually understood in Excel VBA.

Comment: the suggestion to turn off automatic calculations works well. it's just that I have no idea about automatic calculations. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable automatic calculation and events to improve processing speed and reenable when you are done processing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i as Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For i = 1 To 366 
    If range("C" & i + 67) <> "" Then 
    range("E" & i + 67) = "EB": End If
    If Format(range("A" & i + 67), "dddd") = "Sunday" Then
    range("E" & i + 67) = "AP"
    If range("D" & i + 67) = "" Then
    range("D" & i + 67) = "Aspalt"
    End If
    End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'just change xlCalculationActomatic t xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```